# Is there a risk of inbred children with fake fatherhood?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I got an event where my wife cheated on me and got pregnant, but I was unable to prove it. Now her son is listed as my legitimate son. We appear as father and son in family trees, relationship screens etc., even though his actual biological father is definitely someone else.

When I marry him to a close relative from my side of the family, is there a risk that their children will turn inbred? Common sense would say "no", but it seems like the game treats me as the biological father for all intents and purposes, so I have my doubts.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer It's very rewarding, but learning how to play it is a bit of an uphill climb before you get the hang of it and this amazing complexity starts unfolding. So worth it though.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer: Also, once you start down the CK II route, don't expect the oteh 299 games in your backlog to see the light of day any time soon.

Comment: @Wjousts Ha! That's exactly what my cousin told me when he started playing. It sounds like each game lasts longer than a standard game of Civ.

Comment: This event always bugs the heck out of me. I've gotten maybe 30 times and no matter what course of action I take, I just always have to assume it's mine. **Always**. It's kind of unfair that the game is making **me** paranoid, even when my character isn't...

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer I don't know how long a standard game of Civ takes (never got into it), but according to Steam I already played 141 hours of CKII. I have two games, one 83/387 years played and the other 191/387 years played.

Comment: @tpg2114 Treat your wife right and maybe she won't seek solace in the arms of another man...  And you can sleep easier to boot

Comment: @Philipp Is that all active playtime?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, it shouldn't. In case of bastards, the game records the real fatherhood behind the curtain, and calculates the risk of inbreeding by the genetic family ties.

Example character:

```
        birth_name="Aghsartan"
        birth_date="1214.2.3"
        father=582283
        real_father=568231
        mother=583069
```

That also means, that you can inadvertently commit incest, when the real paternity of the characters are unknown to the characters.

If you want to avoid this, you can turn extra character info on, by typing `charinfo on` in the console. The character tooltips will now show you some hidden info, such as their health pool, ethnicity, fertility, biological father and more.

Answer (score 15):

The game mechanics have an internal awareness of who the actual father was, this enables in game events to be triggered such as:

- "I am a bastard"
- "The father's wife is angered"

and my personal favourite:

- "I'm not your son. I'm your brother"

So **IF** the father is of a different family and you marry him off to a relative then there will be no risk of inbreeding.

That is **IF** the father is of a different family and that is a big **IF**, the real father will likely be someone in your court which could include your sons, brothers etc etc.

Comment: ["You put your seed in my daughter's belly, you're fired!"
"But Pa, you can't fire me!" "You're lucky you're my brother, too, or I'd kill you!"](http://www.tv.com/shows/family-guy/road-to-rhode-island-25460/)

Comment: Royalty and rednecks, so far apart on the social ladder, yet both the butt of incest jokes.  Go figure.

Answer (score 4):

It'd be based on their biological father (probably the other guy).

A character's real father is recorded in their stats. This is not normally displayed, but is visible in non-ironman save files or by entering charinfo into the console.

This means that you can safely marry your son to other dynasty members. On the other hand, you probably shouldn't marry him to anyone who might be his half-sister.

Bear in mind that the "but wasn't I away" event can happen with legitimate children, especially if you are paranoid. The child might actually be yours.